# Why is $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ Homeomorphic to $2^{\mathbb{N}^{< \mathbb{N}}}$?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set, product-space, polish-spaces

This question is based off a problem from *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Kechris. In this book, Kechris makes the claim that, when $\{0, 1\}$ is endowed with the discrete topology, then the Cantor space $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is homeomorphic to the set $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}}$ (both endowed with the product topology). I am struggling to see why this is true, and I cannot think of an explicit homeomorphism between the two spaces. Could someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: Basically, because both product topologies are countably indexed and the ("factor") topologies $(\{0,1\}, \tau)$ are discrete...  Try to work through it.  Good book, by the way.  Check out Srivastava's, too.

Comment: There exists a bijection $\pi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$. So, $$(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto (x_{\pi(i)})_{\pi(i) \in \mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}}$$

Comment: @nomen the discreteness of $\{0,1\}$ plays no role, we could have any $X$ there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I.J$ be infinite index sets. Then $\{0,1\}^I \simeq \{0,1\}^J$ (as spaces) iff the sets $I$ and $J$ have the same cardinality. A shuffle of
coordinates is a homeomorphism (if $f: I \to J$ is a bijection, $\hat{f}: \{0,1\}^J \to \{0,1\}^I$ defined by $\hat{f}(g)=g \circ f$ is a homeomorphism)

For the reverse note that the weight of $\{0,1\}^I$ equals $|I|$ and weight ( the minimal size of a base) is a topological invariant.

Comment: I think it would be nice if you write a proof of the direct implication.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf which implication do you mean?

Comment: Homeo implies equal cardinality.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf added the argument.

Comment: What a pity, I'll have to vote up! :-)